# how to replace a part of string to create <li> tags using PHP?

Tags: php, html

The question is extremely easy, but the solution might not.

Let's say this is my text input inside a variable called $description:

```
<p>
text text text
text text text
</p>
<ul>
text text
text text
text text
</ul>
<p>
text text text
text text text
</p>
```

I believe it's already obvious what I need to do. I need to locate all `<ul></ul>` tags inside my string and add `<li></li>` tags for each entry inside, under these conditions:

- I don't know how many `<ul></ul>` tags there might be in total, the function should find all of them
- All list-entries inside each `<ul></ul>` WILL be separated by enter (`\r\n`)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can there be other ul inside a ul? can the ul have attributes?

Comment: Where is that HTML coming from?

Comment: the HTML is coming from an sql database, not really important.

Comment: no, no ul can have another ul inside. it cannot have attributes either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
  function addLI ($in) {
     $in = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $in);
     $lines = explode("\n", $in);
     $out = "";
     $ul = false;
     foreach($lines as $line) {
        if ($ul == false) {
           if (stripos($line, "<ul>") !== false) {
              $ul = true;
           }
        }
        else {
           if (stripos($line, "</ul>") !== false) {
              $ul = false;
           }
           else {
              $line = "<li>" . $line . "</li>";
           }
        }
        $out .= $line . "\n";
     }
     return $out;
  }
```

Edit: first edition worked only with "\n" - now it works with "\n" and "\r\n"

Comment: I have tried all the solutions proposed in this thread, but only this one really worked. Thanks a lot! Thanks others for the efforts!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for string manipulation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Here's my 5 minute solution:

```
// Replaces \r\n with </li><li>
$description = str_replace("\r\n\","</li><li>",$description);

// Removes the extra <li> that will be left at the end of every <ul>
$description = str_replace("<li></ul>","</ul>",$description);

// Adds an <li> to the start of the <ul> tag.
$description = str_replace("<ul>","<ul><li>",$description);
```

Comment: yes, I know that, the problem is identifying the ul tags. do i need to explode the string?

Comment: Ohhh, because other lines (in <p> tags for instance) have the same \r\n?  Or you need to get rid of everything outside the <p> tags?

Answer (score 1):

If it's such a simple case, you can get away with:

```
$html =
  preg_replace_callback('#(?<=<ul>) [^<]+ (?=</ul>)#x', "li", $html);

function li($match) {
    foreach (explode("\n", trim($match[0])) as $line) {
        $text .= "<li>$line</li>\n";
    }
    return "\n" . $text;
}
```

(The callback function needs a better name than `"li"` of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM you can do something like that :

```
<?php
    $html = '<p>text text texttext text text</p><ul>text text\r\ntext text\r\ntext text</ul><p>text text texttext text text</p>';
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML($html);
    $result = $document->getElementsByTagName('ul');

    foreach ($result as $item)
    {
        $liList = explode('\r\n', $item->textContent);
        $ulContent = '';

        foreach ($liList as $li)
        {
            $ulContent .= '<li>' . $li . '</li>';
        }

        $item->nodeValue = $ulContent;
    }

    echo html_entity_decode($document->saveHTML());
```